# Custom vim highlighting

Tags: unix, bash, vim, syntax-highlighting

I am editing some xml right now and I have been leaving myself some comments of things to come back to.  Like this

```
<!-- Question: bla bla -->
```

I am editing with vim right now and I would like vim to highlight Question right now so that I can easily look through my code and find all the places I need to look at.  I know I need to add something in my vimrc but I think that I might be searching for the wrong thing.

**Update**

I tried putting this in my `.vimrc` but it had no effect:

```
syn keyword JakeAnnotation      Question

hi JakeAnnotation gui=bold term=bold cterm=bold
```

**Update 2**

Actually I can see that what I did before had some effect because when I do this:

```
:hi
```

It shows me all of the things that it is highlighting and one of the entries is:

```
JakeAnnotation xxx term=bold cterm=bold ctermbg=6
```

(*and the xxx is formatted correctly*)

This leads me to beleave that I am just not defining Question properly.  Does Question need to be on a line by itself?

**Update 3**

Ok so   to [user 22303's post](https://superuser.com/questions/110054/custom-vim-highlighting/110204#110204) I have this working:

```
highlight MyQuestion cterm=bold term=bold ctermbg=blue ctermfg=black
match MyQuestion /Question/
```

However I suspect that you are only allowed to have one match per file.  Because when I do this:

```
highlight MyQuestion cterm=bold term=bold ctermbg=blue ctermfg=black
match MyQuestion /Question/
highlight MyRelook cterm=bold term=bold ctermbg=blue ctermfg=black
match MyRelook /Another look/
```

The first one stops working.  (But the second one works).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think we've been feeding you some answers that aren't quite right.  Here's something to try that I tested on my machine.

First, create your own new highlight group:

`:highlight MyQuestions guifg=red guibg=green`

Now, specify that the highlight group will exist whenever a pattern is matched:

`:syntax match MyQuestions /Question/`

That should start showing highlight of the text 'Question' on each line that has that text.  To expand to show whole line you would change search text to have wildcards matching entire line, something like this:

`:syntax match MyQuestions /.*Question.*/`

Comment: Actually that only sortive worked...  I suspect that you are only allowed to have one match at a time see update #3...

Comment: @sixtyfootersdude:  Sorry, once again there was minor error.  All of the match commands have to instead be "syntax match" commands.  So instead of [ :match MyQuestions /.*Question.*/ ] you would want to use [ :syntax match MyQuestions /.*Question.*/ ].  That lets you have as many different matches as you want.  These are in fact one of the most common types of commands placed in syntax files.  But you can execute them anywhere you want, either command line, vimrc, or any other scripts.

Comment: Adding `syntax` infront of `match...` in my vimrc file makes match have no effect at all.  Is this where I should be doing this.  Doing it to an open file also has no effect.

Comment: @sixtyfooters:  Not sure what's happening for you, but that's definitely the way to do it.  Test at command line before placing in a script (it's possible syntax settings are getting cleared somewhere in other scripts that are loaded for your file).  Once defined, check what groups exist and what highlighting they have by issuing a bare ":highlight" command (or choosing "Syntax", "Highlight test" from gui menu in gvim).   Remember you want to use highlight command first to create group, then use 'syntax match' to set match pattern.

Comment: @sixtyfooters: I'm assuming you're running vim in a terminal (i.e., not gvim) so that setting the term properties only should work.  It sounds to me like the syntax commands are getting cleared when a new file is loaded and an associated syntax file is running and clearing out all previous syntax commands.  So just to double-check, when using command line are you re-entering these commands every time you load a file?  I think you could try testing with text in new buffer that isn't even saved and doesn't even have a filename assigned yet.

Comment: Brilliant!  That worked.  Just had to change: the first line in my .vimrc from: `syntax on` to `syntax enable`

Comment: Hey if you get a chance could you look at http://superuser.com/questions/112632/vim-custom-highlighting-only-works-sometimes

Comment: It appears that our solution only partially works.  Rather than add further clutter to this thread I opted to create a new one.  It is shown on the link above.

Answer (score 5):

The file you are looking for is a 'syntax' file.  Try looking in `/usr/local/share/vim/syntax/` or `/usr/share/vim/syntax/`.  The file you want is xml.vim.

The simplest thing to do is find the line that has

```
syn keyword xmlTodo         contained TODO FIXME XXX
```

and change it to:

```
syn keyword xmlTodo         contained TODO FIXME XXX Question
```

This will add the 'Todo' highlight to any comment containing the text `Question`.

If you are going to use this for (ever), it would be best to copy the xml.vim into your local `~/.vim/syntax` so that changes to vim won't overwrite your custom syntax file.

**Update**

If you want a similar (sortof) capability in *any* file, I would use the 'goto' command.  I'll admit that this is like hlsearch, which you said annoys you.

While editing, when the cursor is on a word, type `gd` to search from the current point in the file or `gD` to search from the beginning.  Every word in your file that matches the current word is highlighted.  You can type `n` to jump to the next instance of that word.

I tend to do this, because you get highlight and navigation with minimal typing.
You turn off the highlight in the usual way: `:noh[lsearch]`

Comment: Wow!  That sound like what I want to do.  I currently do not have a `~/.vim/ folder.  If I created it and create the file `syntax` do I need to reference it somewhere (maybe in `.vimrc?`) to tell vim to use it?

Comment: Nope.  Vim automatically looks for it (and a few other directories - for example: plugins, color, compiler) and if a syntax file exists in your home area, it takes precedence of the system default.

Comment: Also, just to be clear, you want to create a *directory* `syntax` and put in it a file named `xml.vim`

Comment: Should I put my .vimrc into my .vim dir?

Comment: Beautiful.  That did for sure!  But what if I do not want it to be xml specific?  What if I want it to highlight that in all of my files?  Am I better adding it to my .vimrc or is there a generic file?

Comment: syntax files go in your .vim dir.  Syntax highlight is intended to be language specific.  If you want a similar (sortof) capability in *any* file, I would use the 'goto' command.  I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: Hmm.  Ok Thanks for the advice.  Is there a reason that when I put the things from the syntax file into the vimrc they don't work?  I think that would be one way to make vim highlight those keywords in all files.  Thanks for all of the help.  I am marking this as the best answer.

Comment: Actually, good idea.  Everything in a syntax file is a syntax command.  You can do that, but the syntax files don't include `:syntax` at the beginning of each line (for brevity).  You could add `syntax syn keyword myTodo Question` and `hi def link myTodo ToDo` - this just might work for any file type.  Haven't tried it.  It would highlight the word 'Question' in *every* file though.

Comment: It is mostly working now but not completly.  If you get a chance could you have a peak here?

http://superuser.com/questions/112632/vim-custom-highlighting-only-works-sometimes

Answer (score 2):

You could simply do

```
:set hlsearch
```

And then search for Question

Comment: That is what I have been doing but hlsearch annoys me.  +1, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You have several options.
- one, as Dominik mentioned ... you can search for those one by one (not that practical)
- two, you can do ":g/<-- Question" to get a "list" of them all (a little better, gives an overall picture)
- three, you can set up a highlighting group if you're only using those kind of comments in xml files (I've no idea how xml looks like, so I don't know if there are some other kind of comments in them as well). This would be good if you setted it up in vimrc, since when you refresh vim with a newer version, your xlm.vim file will be gone.

Comment: +1 I like the `:g/` suggestion, but might be tough to apply if 'Question' doesn't immediately follow the comment tag.

Comment: @DaveParillo - ah, yes. well, as i said, i don't know anything about xml so i assumed it was always like so.

Comment: How can I setup a highlighting group?

Comment: @sixtyfootersdude - see ":help e410".

Comment: @Idigas: thanks for the reference.  Had a look but still could not solve my problem.  I added an update in the question.  

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need to put the command in your vimrc.  You can always just enter it at command line and then clear it when you don't want the highlighting anymore.  Commands would be something like this:

:hi Question   guifg=red guibg=blue gui=bold

In gvim (i.e., vim with a gui) that will set the foreground(guifg), background, and general character settings.

if you want to get rid of that higlighting do this:

:hi Question clear

Using vim inside a terminal you can modify to use this command:

:hi Question  ctermfg=red ctermbg=blue term=bold

You can of course put any of those in your vimrc, and you can also combine the gui and term flags into single hi command.

---

### [below added after I read another poster's answer]

Sorry, I was assuming that the syntax of your question lines already matched your syntax file's settings for Vim's built-in 'Question' highlight tag.  Just look at the other answer that mentions the xml syntax file for vim and then you can issue commands above using ToDo highlight group instead of Question.

Comment: Tried :hi Question ctermfg=red ctermbg=blue term=bold but had no effect.

Comment: Sorry, the :hi command merely established how the Question group would be highlighted.  Now you have to specify what areas of document are part of the Question group.  You can do this with a match command:

:match Question /[search pattern]/

or, in your case:

:match Question /Question/

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party but I use `TODO` and `FIXME` for exactly this situation.

Most, if not all, colorschemes will highlight the `TODO` in the following example with some combination of background color, underline and italics :

```
<tree>
  <!--TODO : do I have to add a trunk tag ?-->
  <branch>
    <leaf>caterpillar</leaf>
    <leaf>caterpillar</leaf>
  </branch>
</tree>
```

It doesn't really fit semantically but it works very well from a purely functional point of view.