# Vim highlighting for specific file types (where to put syntax files, vim events, line to put into vimrc)

Tags: unix, vim, syntax-highlighting

I have defined a file time `jak.vim` to offer custom highlighting when I take notes, however it is being applied to some files that do not have the `.jak` extension.  Specifically a file named `progress.jlog`.  Just to test if the problem was specific to that extension I renamed `progress.jlog` to `progress` (no extension) but experienced the same problem.

What I did:

- I created `jak.vim` in the directory `~/.vim/ftdetect`
- I added this line to the top, as described [in the vim reference](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/filetype.html#new-filetype)

  - `au BufRead, BufNewFile *.jak set filetype=jak`
- I restarted vim (:x, and then reopened)

This is what my `~/.vim/ftdetect/jak.vim` looks like:

```bash
au BufRead, BufNewFile *.jak set filetype=jak

syn region JakeSubtitle start=+==+ end=+==+
highlight JakeSubtitle ctermbg=black ctermfg=DarkMagenta

syn region JakeTitle start=+===+ end=+===+
highlight JakeTitle ctermbg=black ctermfg=yellow

syn region JakeMasterTitle start=+====+ end=+====+
highlight JakeMasterTitle cterm=bold term=bold ctermbg=black ctermfg=LightBlue

syn region emphasis start=+<em>+ end=+</em>+
highlight emphasis ctermbg=black ctermfg=yellow

" makes all of the numbered items bold."
" (this works I just don't like the effect.  Decided to change to just highlight the "number)
"syn region numberedItem start=+^\t*\d*)+ end=+\n+"
syn match numberedItem +^\t*\d*)+
highlight numberedItem cterm=bold
```

And just incase you need to know this is what my `.vimrc` looks like:

```bash
"on will override defaults set.  Enable will allow you to set defaults."
" also turns on filetype"
"syntax on"
syntax enable

set nocompatible

" ???"
set backspace=2

"Auto indent"
set ai

"Map jj to Esc so that you do not have to reach for the Esc button"
imap jj <Esc>

"do not allow the search to wrap around the screen, must stop at the bottom."
set nowrapscan

"when doing a search highlight all occurances"
":set hlsearch"

"stop text from wrapping on the screen"
set nowrap

"turn the mouse on while in insert mode"
set mouse=i

"attempting to highlight specific keywords so it is easy to see in code."
"see help e410 for more info."
"see this post I created: https://superuser.com/questions/110054/custom-vim-highlighting"
"Legal colors: Black, DarkBlue, DarkGreen, DarkCyan, DarkRed, DarkMagenta,"
"Brown, DarkYellow, LightGray, LightGrey, Gray, Grey, DarkGray, DarkGrey,"
"Blue, LightBlue, Green, LightGreen, Cyan, LightCyan, Red, LightRed, Magenta,"
"LightMagenta, Yellow, LightYellow, White"
syn keyword JakeKeywords        Question TODO Answer JAKEHTTPS PossibleProblem
highlight JakeKeywords cterm=bold term=bold ctermbg=black ctermfg=Blue


"for case-insensitve searches"
set ignorecase

"Override the 'ignorecase' option if the search pattern contains upper"
"case characters.  Only used when the search pattern is typed and"
"'ignorecase' option is on."
set smartcase


"use indents as the folding method"
set foldmethod=indent

"make vim save and load the folding of the document each time it loads"
"also places the cursor in the last place that it was left."
au BufWinLeave * mkview
au BufWinEnter * silent loadview
```

---

## Update

I found  [nsharish's post](https://superuser.com/questions/113455/vim-highlighting-for-specific-file-types/115294#115294) to be very helpfull.  They suggested that I add this to my vimrc:

```bash
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.jak set filetype=jak
```

and add my `jak.vim` file to `~/.vim/syntax`

Unfortunately that code conflicts with these two lines (in my vimrc)

```bash
au BufWinLeave *.c mkview
au BufWinEnter *.c silent loadview
```

I use these two to save my folds, cursor location, etc when loading vim (see `:help lo`).  If I comment out those two lines nsharish's suggestion works like a charm.  With those two lines there is no highlighting in any of my files.

## Conclusion

I marked  [nsharish's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/113455/vim-highlighting-for-specific-file-types/115294#115294) as the best answer (because it as most helpful to me).  However this is how I solved the problem:

Nsharish was right I needed this line in my `.vimrc`:

```bash
syntax enable
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.jak set filetype=jak
```

And I needed to move my `jak.vim` file to `~/.vim/syntax`.

However as noted above there was a conflict with these lines:

```bash
au BufWinLeave * mkview
au BufWinEnter * silent loadview
```

When these lines were commented the highlighting worked.

What I needed to do was to change the `...set filetype...` to this:

```bash
au BufWinEnter,BufRead,BufNewFile *.jak set filetype=jak
```

I think that the BufWinEnter is called **after** the BufRead/BufNew file so the highlighting was being overwritten by the formatting saved from last time.

Thank again to nsharish for helping me to come up with this solution.

Comment: in what sense do the *.c statements conflict with the *.jak statement?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Did you try this..

- Put your jak.vim in **.vim/syntax** folder
- put the following lines only in your .vimrc file.

```
syntax enable
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.jak set filetype=jak
```

I tried this with your jak.vim file.... It worked fine for me....

I am using vim7.2...
**edit:**
Try this,
I had the same problem with those mkview and loadview lines... just set filetype once in the file and it will be retained then

Open the file, then do "**:set ft=jak**", save the file and quit vim.... 
Now reopen the file... syntax highlighting should work now...
*mkview* and *loadview* seems to save the last syntax highlight settings also....

Comment: trying right now...  But do you know what the .vim/ftdetect/ folder does?  The behavior I am experiencing is that any formatting file in there applies to all file types.

Comment: Huh, that partially worked..  However there was a conflict with two other lines in my vimrc.  See my update.

Answer (score 2):

I must admit, I don't know for certain how useful this would be to you... But...

http://beerpla.net/2008/04/02/how-to-add-a-vim-file-extension-to-syntax-highlighting/

I have appended the text incase the page is taken down... Or altered...

How To Add A File Extension To vim Syntax Highlighting
Posted by Artem Russakovskii on April 2nd, 2008 in Databases, Linux, Programming
24 delicious saves  2 diggs 
Share
3retweet

Updated: July 8th, 2009

Today I was asked a question about defining custom extensions for vim syntax highlighting such that, for example, vim would know that example.lmx is actually of type xml and apply xml syntax highlighting to it. I know vim already automatically does it not just based on extension but by looking for certain strings inside the text, like

After digging around I found the solution. Add the following to ~/.vimrc (the vim configuration file):

1
2
3
syntax on
filetype on
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.lmx set filetype=xml
After applying it, my .lmx file is highlighted:

Same principle works, for instance, for mysql dumps that I have to do from time to time. If they don't have a .sql extension, you'll get something like:

After

1
2
3
syntax on
filetype on
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.dump set filetype=sql
everything is fine:

But why and how does it work, you ask?

:help au    :au[tocmd] [group] {event} {pat} [nested] {cmd}

Add {cmd} to the list of commands that Vim will execute automatically on {event} for a file matching {pat}.
:help BufNewFile    When starting to edit a file that doesn't exist.
:help BufRead   When starting to edit a new buffer, after reading the file into the buffer.
:help filetype  will actually tell this whole story in part B.
And that's how you do it, folks.

Comment: Huh, going to have better look into this soon, but looks useful..

Comment: Well, that may potentially solve one problem but I don't think that it will solve this prob...  I think that the key to this has to do with the `.vim/ftdetect` directory...

Comment: I honestly don't even use VIM, so I'll have to take your word on it...

Answer (score 1):

I tried reproducing what you've done, but couldn't get the filetype applied to other extensions.

I also found that this helped:

The Vim help-file for 'new-filetype' mentions creating your own 'filetype.vim' in `~/.vim/filetype.vim`
and writing your auto commands in that file:

```
if exists("did_load_filetypes")
  finish
endif
augroup filetypedetect
  au! BufRead,BufNewFile *.jak      setfiletype jak
augroup END
```

All those syntax and highlight commands from your jak.vim need to stored under `~/.vim/syntax`, so copy it to `~/.vim/syntax/jak.vim` (without the `au` command).

You'll also have to quit Vim and restart to pick up the changes.

Answer (score 1):

I think things might be twisted around, but I'm no vim expert.

Your syntax highlighting file should be in the syntax directory. The things in nsharish's advice might be what goes into the file you place inside of ftdetect.

This part:

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.jak set filetype=jak
```

In .vimrc, you may also need to add a line like:

```
au! syntax jak source $VIM/syntax/jak.vim
```

IMHO, it makes more sense this way. I hope this helps.